# multiple displayed after search

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I implement code that search recycler view but when i write more than one words that belongs to same cardview i get that card displayed multiple time. I need to be displayed only one time and if they match most of my words they need to be displayed first on list.

**Search part**

```
if (charString.contains(",")) {
  String searchChar[] = charString.split(",");
  for (int i = 0; i < searchChar.length; i++) {

    if (androidVersion.getApi().toLowerCase().contains(searchChar[i]) || androidVersion
        .getName()
        .toLowerCase().contains(searchChar[i]) || androidVersion.getVer().toLowerCase()
        .contains(searchChar[i])) {

      filteredList.add(androidVersion);
    }
  }
} else {
  if (androidVersion.getApi().toLowerCase().contains(charString) || androidVersion.getName()
      .toLowerCase().contains(charString) || androidVersion.getVer().toLowerCase()
      .contains(charString)) {

    filteredList.add(androidVersion);
  }
}
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSOt2.png)

Answer (score 0):

**What do you do?** Make it look up.

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
            {return  false; }

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


            newText = newText.toLowerCase();

            final ArrayList<DictObjectModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<DictObjectModel>();

            for (int i = 0; i < wordcombimelist.size(); i++) {

                final String text = wordcombimelist.get(i).toLowerCase();
                if (text.contains(newText)) {

                    filteredList.add(new DictObjectModel(wordcombimelist.get(i),meancombimelist.get(i)));
                }
            }
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(filteredList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


            return true;
        }
    });
```